# how can i exclude FRI and SAT days from the calculation of days passed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to exclude FRI and SAT days from the formula which counts the days from date in cell A1 until the date of Today(), and subtracts A1 from Today()

i have already the formula which checks first if A1 has a value, if yes subtracts the value from Today(), if not it will say "NO  VALUE"

i also know there is  code to exclude FRI and SAT but i'm having a hard time incorporating it into my formula:

This will count 8 days from Start_Date in A1, and excludes FRI and SAT:

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(A1,8,7)
```

This is my current formula which shows the number of days, but i want it to skip FRI and SAT:

```
=IF((A1<>""),((TODAY()-A1)),"NO VALUE")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NETWORKDAYS rather than WORKDAY:

```
=IF(A1<>"",NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A1,TODAY(),7),"NO VALUE")
```

Comment: Just an observation. `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` is available only in Excel 2010 or higher.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns True, but since OP was already using `WORKDAY.INTL` I think we can assume a suitable version. :)

Comment: Nice one! I did not think about that.

Comment: @Rory thanks a lot for the suggestion, it seems to work however even if it has the "7" indicating to skip FRI and SAT, for some reason its only skiping one day, not both...example A1 is 22APR, today is 29, its showing me a difference of 6 days, shouldn't it be 5 days?

Comment: @Rory i think its a confusion , as i was not counting the current day(today), so yes if i take into account today as 1, then yes it will be 6 days between 22APR-29APR excluding FRI and SAt

Comment: @Sergiu It includes both start and end days. If you don't want that, you'll need to subtract 1.

Comment: @Rory you;re right :) took me sometime to grasp it. both start and end days being captured is perfect for my case. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the best way to do it but I found a work around.

You can calculate the total number of day and remove the number of Friday and remove the number of Saturday.

I found [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-day-of-week-between-dates) that count how many Friday in a specific date range.

For example:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT(Date1&":"&Date2)))=5))
```

It basically retrieve all the date in the range in their numerical value and test if if it is a Saturday and give you the amount of Saturday between 2 dates.

In your case you could use it to remove the Friday and Saturday like below:

```
=IF((A1<>""),((TODAY()-A1-SUMPRODUCT(-(WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT(A1&":"&B1)))=5)) -SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT(A1&":"&B1)))=6)))),"NO VALUE")
```

Where B1 is  today's date.

And example:

[example using the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Ju1.png)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Rotemya, Nels, your solution works as well. thank you for the help!